# How to translate isTRUE to Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it possible to translate the R function `isTRUE` to Rcpp? And if so, how?

The R function:

```
function (x) 
is.logical(x) && length(x) == 1L && !is.na(x) && x
```

I am struggling with the first and third part. How can I check if the input is of type boolean or logical? And how can I test for NA when the input type is not known?

I know that I can check if the length is 1 with

```
x.length()  == 1  /  x.size() == 1
```

Comment: How about a function with signature `foo(bool x)` and let Rcpp attributes do the rest?

Comment: What if x is a string or integer? And how would i test for NA then?

Comment: See Dirk's answer if `x` can have different types. I had assumed these tests where only for input validation.

Answer (score 4):

It is already implemented in [this header file](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/logical/is.h) as

```
template <bool NA, typename T>
inline bool is_true( const Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA,T>& x){
    return const_cast< Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA,T>& >(x).is_true() ;
}
```

That of course references [another file ...](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/logical/SingleLogicalResult.h) and all the template-meta-programming is not for the faint of heart.  You can also do what you sketch, see [this Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/) about dynamic dispatch to see an example of testing for types at run-time.

Comment: I am not able to create a small function with it. How would I use it if the input could be an integer, a string, a boolean or NULL? I am always getting this kind of error `no matching function for call to 'is_true(...&)'`

Comment: See the Rcpp Gallery post: you could pass a `SEXP` and branch based on the payload of the `SEXP`.